# How do you type a square root for the surface plotter?

Tags: mesh, mathematics

For the "Add Z function surface" addon, I tried typing $(1 - x**2 - y**2)**(1/2)$ and $pow(1 - x**2 - y**2,(1/2))$ and neither plotted, what do I do differently?

Comment: can you add a screen shot of precisely what you've typed that generates the error?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the *XYZ Math Surface* function, just use `sqrt`.  The equations are python expressions, if that helps.

Also, you don't use x and y directly to set z.  If your equation is simple, set x to u and y to v and use u and v instead.

Here is a working example:

[image: XYZ function showing working sqrt]

If you're getting an error with this, it's probably because you have U and V ranges set up so that you're trying to take the square root of a negative number.  It has nothing to do with the equation input format, although the error messages might make it look that way.

If you are getting an error message, look at your system console.  If you find something like this:

```
[Add X, Y, Z Function Surface]:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\addons\add_mesh_extra_objects\add_mesh_3d_function_surface.py", line 327, in xyz_function_surface_faces
    float(eval(*expr_args_z))))
ValueError: math domain error
```

that is the reason.

Comment: Nope, still get an error.

Comment: If you have more complicated expressions like xy^2 + x^2y + x - y - y^2 + xy and so on, how do you efficiently calculate the min and max for the square root function?

Comment: @StackQuest functions like `sqrt(x)` have a _domain_: values of x that they are defined for.  In the case of `sqrt(x)` the domain requires x to be >= 0. so if you want to use, say x^2 - y^2 for 'x' you find the domain by using x^2 - y^2 >= 0 or x^2 >= y^2.  It's not always easy.